# Expire all sessions for a particular user?

Tags: session, web-applications, clojure, ring

What's a good way to expire all sessions for a particular user? I thought of maintaining of separate map of user->session, but I'm not sure how to update the map when the session cookies expire.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all sessions in memory using an atom or something similar (which I don't think to be something production-wise) you can do this:

Store sessions in a map with own properties:

```
sessions = {
  s1 -> {...}
  s2 -> {...}
  s3 -> {...}
  ...
}
```

Store user sessions in a separate map of sets:

```
user-sessions = {
 user1 -> #{s1 s2 s3}
 user2 -> #{s4 s5 s6}
}
```

You'll need to solve the following operations which need to update the set:

- Add new session :s to :user

  (assoc user-sessions :user (conj (:user user-sessions) :s))
- Remove session :s from :user

  (assoc user-sessions :user (disj (:user user-sessions) :s))